# Search posts by tags with "OR" condition

Tags: support, search, tag-search

Is there a way to search Stack Overflow questions containing either one of two tags? In other words, search for `[tag1] || [tag2]`

I noticed that when normally searching with two tags, only questions with *both* tags are displayed, but I want to see all questions containing either one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

have you tried?

```
[tag1] or [tag2]
```

Also [additional tips & tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in the help-centre.